# URL rewrite pattern repeating replacement

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am hoping that someone can see what I am not seeing here.  I am trying to create a URL rewrite to implement a fix.  We have a URL with the query string

account/register?365-3454-xxxx

and we need to add id= to the query string at the beginning like so:

account/register?id=365-3454-xxxx

Here is the code we have written but it triggers a  loop of

account/register?id=id=id=id=id=id=id=id=id=id=id=id=id=id=365-3454-xxxx

```
<rule name="365 to Id=365" stopProcessing="true">          
  <match url="^Account/Register$" />
     <conditions>
         <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)365(.*)" />
     </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}?{C:1}Id=365{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

I'm assuming it is because it is replacing and reading 365 again and again.  I tried append=true but same thing.  How do we get the URL rewrite to simply add "id=" at the beginning of the string for URLS with query strings starting with "365"?   Is there a way to prevent the replacement from happening more than once?

Comment: Please add a solution below in the answer space. I rolled back your edit to the question

Answer (score 0):

You should use condition like this:

```
<rule name="365 to Id=365" stopProcessing="true">          
 <match url="^Account/Register$" />
   <conditions>
     <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=365(.*)" />
   </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}?Id=365{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: This replaces 365 with id= so we get this: Account/Register?Id=-3454-xxxx  I am at bit of a loss of how to keep the 365 so we get id=365-xxxxxx-xxxxx from ?365-xxxxxx-xxxxx

Comment: Its value in the url is "{R:0}?Id=365{C:1}", there are 365 in it, please check if your url is correct.